# Redmine REST API Parameter GET /issues.json?assigned_to_id=me doesn't work

Tags: api, redmine

I am using Redmine 3.3.3 version.

I want to query only for Issues which are assigned to one user.

Example Redmine-User-Login its "vishal-px" 
so I hoped that GET /issues.json?assigned_to_id=me will deliver issues assigned to vishal-px.

Even if I try GET /issues.json?assigned_to_id=342710 it doesn't work.
It always returns the blank response.

```
{
  issues: [ ],
  total_count: 0,
  offset: 0,
  limit: 2
}
```

Is there any solution for this bug?

Comment: But are there any issues actually assigned to that user?

Comment: Yes, vishal-px has 9 Issues

Comment: Does the XML endpoint give you anything other than the JSON one?

Comment: No,

Here is my XML response :

<issues total_count="0" offset="0" limit="25" type="array"/>

Answer (score 0):

My problem gets solved, After setup of Basic authentication.
Now I am able to retrieve data through API.